# Saving M2M relationship via inline formset

Tags: django, formset, inline-formset, m2m

I spent a lot of hours searching for a feature which I think should be quite a basic functionality in Django. But I just can't get it working, or it is just not possible with Django - which would be very disappointing ...

OK, I have two models, let's say a `Contact` and an `Address` model. A Contact can have many Addresses and an Address may belong to several Contacts. A classical many-to-many-relationship.

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    ... (some other attributes)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address)

class Address(models.Model):
    ... (some attributes)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact) # <- needed for inline formset
```

I have a form for the Contact model and included there an inline formset for Addresses. The idea is that I have an Addresses MultiSelect widget in the Contact form (to select from already saved Addresses) and dynamically add new Addresses via the inline formset.

However, adding Addresses via the inline formset will save the Address instances, but no entry in the through table is saved to mark the relationship between the Contact and the newly saved Address. This also means that this newly saved Address is not selected in the MultiSelect field upon viewing the Contact instance with an EditView.

I use `save(commit=False)` when saving the Address and the Contact instances because I need to add additional data before saving. I know that you then have to use `save_m2m()` somehow, but it just doesn't work.

The Address model has a foreign key relationship to the Contact model by the way, otherwise I am not able to use an inline formset.

**Some code of my view when the form is valid and about to be saved:**

```
  self.object = form.save(commit=False)
  self.object.someAttribute = theAttributeValue # just adding some attribute
  self.object.save()
  # In case there is a many-to-many relationship to another model, we need to use the save_m2m() method
  form.save_m2m()

  for formset in formsets:
      formset.instance = self.object
      saved_formset = formset.save(commit=False)

      """
      If you call formset.save(commit=False), objects will not be deleted automatically. You’ll need to call
      delete() on each of the formset.deleted_objects to actually delete them. See also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/#django.forms.formsets.BaseFormSet.can_delete
      """
      for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
          obj.delete()

      for form in saved_formset:
          form.someAttribute = theAttributeValue
          form.save()

      formset.save_m2m()
```

Please help me out here, it's just getting crazy. There must be a way to make this work, right? What am I not seeing?

Comment: "The Address model has a foreign key relationship to the Contact model by the way, otherwise I am not able to use an inline formset" - does this mean you have two kind of relations between `Contact` and `Address` (ManyToMany specified in `Contact` model & ForeignKey in `Address` model)?

Comment: Exactly. That does not make much sense, but - as I said - otherwise I get a Django error when viewing the create/update form stating that the Address model needs a foreign key to the Contact model. I just updated the model description above.

Comment: Now after resetting my migrations (needed to) and trying to make initial migrations (with the existing tables), I run again in a circular dependency Django error:
django.db.migrations.graph.CircularDependencyError: addresses.0001_initial, contacts.0001_initial

I had this before, somehow I made it working when I posted my issue. But in general, having a ForeignKey <-> ManyToMany relationship just does not seem to work.

But still, I can't believe that the illustrated use-case is not possible with Django, it just feels like a basic functionality to me. What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

To manage your circular depencies, I recommend switching from:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    ... (some other attributes)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address)

class Address(models.Model):
    ... (some attributes)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact) # <- needed for inline formset
```

to:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    ... (some other attributes)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.Address')

class Address(models.Model):
    ... (some attributes)
    contact = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Contact') # <- needed for inline formset
```

Do you see the difference in how I defined the relations? Rather than pass in a model class, I pass in the 'string mapping' for the model class. Then Django handles the rest.

This *should* handle your circular dependency issues. And *might* address any glitches had with `formsets`. However, as I tend to stay away from `formsets` I can't say for certain.

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks for your help. As a matter of fact, I am already using the 'string mapping' to avoid circular dependencies. The above example is just an abstraction from my real models.
For some reason I get the manytomany with foreignkey to work again without circular dependency error (don't ask me what is going on here ;)
BUT: the main problem still exists: the Address instance which I create via the inline formset is saved in the addresses.address table - but not the manytomany-relationship (meaning no entry in the contacts_contact_addresses through table which is created automatically) :(